# Query mongoose subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to write an app that manages shifts within employments. Therefore I created a Schema for Employments, that has a field `shifts: [Shift]`where Shift is the Schema that contains a `startDate: Date` field.

Now I want to query the Database to return the Employments that have Shifts with the condition: `startTimestamp <= startDate <= endTimestamp` to display the result in a calendar.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do the query and I couldn't find some deeper explanations for mongoose queries. It would be nice, if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I tried the following

```
  .find(
    {customer: req.user.customer,
    'shifts.startDate': {$gte: req.params.startDate, $lte: req.params.endDate} })
```

But that does not work. I should add, that every Employment has a customer field and every request should only return Employments belonging to the customer the current user belongs to

Comment: I'm sure the answer is in one of these questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+query+subdocument

Comment: Thank you, but I can't transfer these solutions to my problem ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When matching an array field element within a range, use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to ensure that both terms of the match are satisfied by the *same* element.

```
MyModel.find({
    customer: req.user.customer,
    shifts: {$elemMatch: {startDate: {$gte: req.params.startDate, 
                                      $lte: req.params.endDate}}}
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However there was a small problem with your solution: one cannot use `req.params.*` directly because there is no internal conversion from string to integer. One has to write `parseInt(req.params.*)`....
That might be helpful for others that encounter the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it;

```
db.employments.find({shifts.startDate: {$gte: startTimestamp, $lt: endTimestamp}});
```